# Is there a manga with a scene where Shinji chokes Asuka?

Tags: neon-genesis-evangelion

I'm trying to find the manga where Shinji chokes Asuka.
[image: picture]

Does it exist? If yes then please help me find it.

Comment: Related: [Why does Evangelion manga's plot diverge from the anime?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/42803) (not yet answered)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, I don't believe there is. The entirety of Instrumentality happens in the last volume of the Sadamoto manga (volume 14) and there was no kitchen scene during instrumetality (where coffee is spilled and Shinji strangles Asuka while standing up) and when instrumentality ended, we were taken to a new stage of the world completely back to normal so there wasn't a beach scene either.

However, there was a scene that wasn't in the anime where Shinji visits Asuka in the hospital and she gets out of bed and chokes *him*.

Comment: Can you please advice me what volume to look for the hospital scene you mentioned?

Comment: @IV In my copy of VIZ Media's books, it's in volume 11, Stage 75 "Broken Heart", sequence starts on page 133