# What is the logic behind releasing manga before anime?

Tags: anime-production, manga-production

Manga and anime both are same story, then why do they still release the manga?

My reasoning:

1. Manga readers think that they already know the story, so they don't need to watch the anime (anime viewers will drop)
2. Anime watchers don't want to read the manga (manga readers will drop)

What I am thinking is, once manga is adopted to an anime, they don't need to publish manga.

Comment: Related: [Why do anime have manga adaptations? Why don't authors just focus on one medium at a time?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/34119), [Why don't anime shows finish the manga?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/34468)

Comment: i read that  post before put this question, in my opinion both questions are different..

Comment: That's why Aki wrote these other questions are "related", not "duplicate". That means you'll find interesting information about the topic of your question there, not the actual answer.

Comment: You may as well ask "Why did JK Rowling keep writing Harry Potter books when the movies started coming out?". Different markets, different timing, and people definitely spent lots of money on both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some anime original series but we'll focus on those that were based on manga.

Manga is released before an anime because *an anime is an adaptation of the manga.* Look here, if we do as you say and stop publishing manga the moment an anime series is started, then how are the animation team supposed to continue the story? Their script and everything that happens in the anime is based on what happens in the manga. *Writing a script is not the same as making a manga.* A mangaka is not the same as a scriptwriter.

Second, *the source material do not adjust for its anime. Rather, the anime adjusts for its source material*. There are anime that did not get enough episodes or whose next seasons were delayed because it was [catching up to the manga](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OvertookTheManga). A good example is *Attack on Titan*. Here, the mangaka was not forced to speed up release to continue the anime. Rather, they waited for Isayama's story to develop. In *Tokyo Ghoul*, the second season had a different ending but this did not affect nor force the mangaka to change or adjust his manga's ending or sequel.

Third, I don't get the point of the mangaka being forced to stop publishing their story once it gets an anime adaptation. A manga or light novel being adapted to an anime is usually an indicator that *the series is popular*. All the more reason for them to continue the manga and maintain the readers' interests as this would contribute to its chances getting another season if it remains popular. Also, *I highly doubt that publishers would allow a popular series to stop publishing just because it's getting an anime adaptation*. That would drive away consumers which is kind of counter-intuitive.

Comment: Somewhat related to your answer: https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2351/has-an-anime-ever-come-out-before-the-manga-was-published

Comment: @Dimitrimx Thanks for the info! I structured my answer to focus on those anime based on manga since this is what the OP seems to have a problem on. Nevertheless, yes, it is worth noting that there are times when a manga is based on an anime because the anime came first.

Comment: Also, manga is a much bigger business in Japan than it is in the West, so to some extent the anime could be considered a promotion to help sell more of the manga rather than it being the primary medium.